# Application Crashes during validating Mobile Number on TextChange Event

Tags: android

In my application i want to validate mobile number on touch event of EditText textmobile. I do not want to allow string "033" at place (0, 3). But when i write something in EditBox application crashes. Other validations on mobileText are fine like invalid characters, etc.

```
private void makeListener(EditText field, final int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Validation.isMobileGoodorNot(textmobile);
            }

    });
```

here is method:

```
public static boolean isMobileUfoneorNot(EditText textmobile) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if ( !textmobile.getText().toString().substring(0, 3).equals("033"))

         {

              textmobile.setError("Enter Ufone number only");
              return false;
          }
     return true;
}
```

Here is logcat:

```
10-24 11:14:54.928: E/Trace(3722): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.Validation.isMobileUfoneorNot(Validation.java:96)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0$5.beforeTextChanged(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:306)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:7498)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.widget.TextView.access$700(TextView.java:235)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.beforeTextChanged(TextView.java:9410)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendBeforeTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:954)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:464)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:678)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:196)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:315)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-24 11:15:01.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 11:15:44.801: E/Trace(4143): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.Validation.isMobileUfoneorNot(Validation.java:96)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0$5.onTextChanged(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:313)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7533)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7592)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9416)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:678)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:196)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:315)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-24 11:15:49.396: E/AndroidRuntime(4143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application crashes because `u have not handled the scenario when the text is less than 3 chars in your if condition`.

In ur `If` condition, you need to do something like -

```
textmobile.getText().toString().length()>3 && !textmobile.getText().toString().substring(0, 3).equals("033")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`textmobile.getText().toString().substring(0, 3).equals("033")`

to

```
textmobile.getText().toString().substring(0, 2).equals("033")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `textMobile` string variable's length greater than `3` ? 
Log show us length is `0`. Check your `textMobile` variable length and assign it with `s.toString` in  `afterTextChanged` method.